# Передача данных между C++ dll и .Net приложением

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

Библиотека и приложение расположены на одном компьютере. Реализовал через `CreateFileMapping` в C++ и `MemoryMappedFile` в C#.

В С++ имеется стек, в который приходят данные и поток, который читает первый байт в выделенной памяти и если установлен флаг готовности, то отправляет пакет данных из стека. В C# поток читает первый байт и если данные готовы, то читает их и пишет в первый байт флаг, о том, что данные считаны. В такой реализации не достаточно скорости работы. При большом потоке данных стек переполняется.

Возможно ли как то решить эту проблему?

Возможно передать в C# ссылку на стек и пользоваться им в C#?

Или, возможно, есть способ организовать память так, чтобы пользоваться ей как стеком. Писать в конец, а читать сначала.

---

Создал вот такой клиент-сервер:
Клиент (C++, win32):

```
// TcpClient.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

SOCKET s; //Socket handle

//Send text data to a remote computer
//int PASCAL send(SOCKET, const char*, int, int);

//CONNECTTOHOST – Connects to a remote host
bool ConnectToHost(int PortNo, char* IPAddress)
{
    //Start up Winsock…
    WSADATA wsadata;

    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);

    //Did something happen?
    if (error)
        return false;

    //Did we get the right Winsock version?
    if(wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202)
    {
        WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
        return false;
    }

    //Fill out the information needed to initialize a socket…
    SOCKADDR_IN target; //Socket address information

    target.sin_family = AF_INET; // address family Internet
    target.sin_port = htons(PortNo); //Port to connect on
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPAddress); //Target IP

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //Create socket
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return false; //Couldn't create the socket
    }

    //Try connecting...

    if (connect(s, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return false; //Couldn't connect
    }
    else
        return true; //Success
}

//CLOSECONNECTION – shuts down the socket and closes any connection on it
void CloseConnection()
{
    //Close the socket if it exists
    if (s)
        closesocket(s);

    WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
}

void send_int(SOCKET s, int val)
{
    char val_char[4];
    *((int*)val_char) = val;
    send(s, val_char, sizeof(int), 0);
}

void send_str(SOCKET s, const char * str)
{
    send_int(s, strlen(str));
    send(s, str, strlen(str), 0);
}

int main()
{
    bool is_connected = ConnectToHost(7777, "192.168.1.129");
    std::cout << is_connected;

    if (is_connected)
    {
        send_str(s, "start");
        std::string pack;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
        {
            send_str(s, "23.10.2015 10:30:00;4;62669;1268916675;\n");
        }

        send_str(s, "end");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

И вот такой сервер (C#):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace CSharpConnector
{
    class MessageManager
    {
        int msg_count = 0;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        // Слушатель сокетов
        private TcpListener tcp_listener;
        // Поток для чтения из сокета
        private Thread tcp_thread_handler;
        // Флаг работы потока сервера
        bool is_server_running;
        // Поток для каждого нового клиента
        private Thread connection_thread;

        public MessageManager()
        {
            // Создаем слушатель
            tcp_listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.129"), Convert.ToInt32("7777"));
            tcp_listener.Server.ReceiveBufferSize = 1000;

        }

        public void StartThreads()
        {
            is_server_running = true;

            tcp_thread_handler = new Thread(() => keep_listener());
            tcp_thread_handler.Name = "keep_listener";
            tcp_thread_handler.IsBackground = true;
            tcp_thread_handler.Start();

            // Стуртуем слушатель
            tcp_listener.Start();
        }

        private void keep_listener()
        {
            // While the server is running
            while (is_server_running == true)
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient;

                if (tcp_listener != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        tcpClient = tcp_listener.AcceptTcpClient(); // Otherwise this will block the UI // Called when a Client Connect

                        connection_thread = new Thread(() => connection_handler(tcpClient));
                        connection_thread.IsBackground = true;
                        connection_thread.Start();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void connection_handler(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            Receiver receiver = new Receiver();

            string msg;

            // Keep waiting for a message from the user
            while (is_server_running == true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);

                if (tcpClient.Available == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                msg = receiver.ReceiveMessageFromClient(tcpClient);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if(msg.Contains("start"))
                {
                    sw.Start();
                }

                //Debug.WriteLine(msg, "MessageManager // connection_handler");

                if(msg.Contains("end"))
                {
                    sw.Stop();
                    Debug.WriteLine("Stop. msc = " + sw.Elapsed, "MessageManager // connection_handler");
                }

            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            is_server_running = false;
            tcp_listener.Server.Close();
            tcp_listener.Stop();            

        }
    }

    public class Receiver
    {
        string result;
        NetworkStream nw_stream;

        public Receiver()
        {
            result = "";
        }

        public string ReceiveMessageFromClient(TcpClient client)
        {
            result = null;            

            if (client == null
                || !client.Connected)
            {
                return result;
            }

            nw_stream = client.GetStream();

            if (!nw_stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                return result;
            }

            try
            {
                byte[] buff_size = new byte[4];
                int buff_size_int;

                nw_stream.Read(buff_size, 0, 4);
                buff_size_int = BitConverter.ToInt32(buff_size, 0);

                byte[] buff = new byte[buff_size_int];
                nw_stream.Read(buff, 0, buff_size_int);

                result = Encoding.Default.GetString(buff);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[client.Available];

                nw_stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.Available);
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }       
}
```

Скорость передачи 10 000 строк равна, приблизительно 10 секундам. Через управляемую память это значение около 12 секунд. Возможно я не так использую сокеты. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А подключить С++ библиотеку в С#? Или обернуть С++ библиотеку в COM и подключить в C#?

Comment: Данные появляются в C++ библиотеке. И нужно именно оттуда их нужно передать в C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такая конструкция позволяет передать 100 000 записей менее чем за секунду (00:00:00.6771615):
1. Клиент:

```
// TcpClient.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

SOCKET s; //Socket handle

//Send text data to a remote computer
//int PASCAL send(SOCKET, const char*, int, int);

//CONNECTTOHOST – Connects to a remote host
bool ConnectToHost(int PortNo, char* IPAddress)
{
    //Start up Winsock…
    WSADATA wsadata;

    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);

    //Did something happen?
    if (error)
        return false;

    //Did we get the right Winsock version?
    if(wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202)
    {
        WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
        return false;
    }

    //Fill out the information needed to initialize a socket…
    SOCKADDR_IN target; //Socket address information

    target.sin_family = AF_INET; // address family Internet
    target.sin_port = htons(PortNo); //Port to connect on
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPAddress); //Target IP

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //Create socket
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return false; //Couldn't create the socket
    }

    //Try connecting...

    if (connect(s, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return false; //Couldn't connect
    }
    else
        return true; //Success
}

//CLOSECONNECTION – shuts down the socket and closes any connection on it
void CloseConnection()
{
    //Close the socket if it exists
    if (s)
        closesocket(s);

    WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
}

void send_int(SOCKET s, int val)
{
    char val_char[4];
    *((int*)val_char) = val;
    send(s, val_char, sizeof(int), 0);
}

void send_str(SOCKET s, const char * str)
{
    send_int(s, strlen(str));
    send(s, str, strlen(str), 0);
}

int main()
{
    bool is_connected = ConnectToHost(7777, "127.0.0.1");
    std::cout << is_connected;

    if (is_connected)
    {
        send_str(s, "start");
        std::string pack;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
        {
            send_str(s, "23.10.2015 10:30:00;4;62669;1268916675;\n");
        }

        send_str(s, "end");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Сервер:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace CSharpConnector
{
    class MessageManager
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        // Слушатель сокетов
        private TcpListener tcp_listener;
        // Поток для чтения из сокета
        private Thread tcp_thread_handler;

        // Массив данных
        List<string> data;

        // Флаг работы сервера
        bool is_server_running;

        public MessageManager()
        {
            // Инициализируем массив данных
            data = new List<string>();

            // Создаем слушатель
            tcp_listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32("7777"));

            //tcp_listener.Server.ReceiveBufferSize = 1000;
            // Стуртуем слушатель
            tcp_listener.Start();


        }

        public void StartThreads()
        {

            // Установим флаг работы сервера
            is_server_running = true;
            // Создаем поток для ожидания подключения клиентов
            tcp_thread_handler = new Thread(() => keep_listener());
            // Задаем имя потока
            tcp_thread_handler.Name = "keep_listener";
            // Устанавливаем признак фонового потока
            tcp_thread_handler.IsBackground = true;
            // Стартуем поток
            tcp_thread_handler.Start();
        }

        private void keep_listener()
        {
            // Пока сервер работает
            while (is_server_running == true)
            {
                // Инициализируем клиента
                TcpClient tcpClient;

                // Если слушатель уже создан
                if (tcp_listener != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Подключаем нового клиента
                        tcpClient = tcp_listener.AcceptTcpClient(); 

                        // Инициализируем буфер
                        byte[] buff = new byte[1];

                        // Вызываем ожидание получения данных. Ничего не получаем, а только вызываем callback
                        tcpClient.GetStream().BeginRead(buff, 0, 0, read_buff_size, tcpClient.GetStream());

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // В качестве параметра нам пришел поток
        private void read_buff_size(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            // Создаем буфер
            byte[] buff = new byte[4];
            // Переменная которая хранит размер буфера
            int buff_size;
            // Переменная хранит ссылку на поток
            NetworkStream ns = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;
            // Обработаем завершение чтения
            ns.EndRead(ar);

            // Читаем из потока размер буфера
            ns.Read(buff, 0, 4);

            // Преобразуем размер данных в число
            buff_size = BitConverter.ToInt32(buff, 0);

            // Буфер данных
            byte[] data_buff = new byte[buff_size];

            // Читаем данные
            ns.Read(data_buff, 0, buff_size);

            // Добавялем данные в массив
            data.Add(Encoding.Default.GetString(data_buff));

            // Если передали старт
            if (data.Last().Contains("start"))
            {
                // Сбросим счетчик
                sw.Reset();
                // Стартуем счетчик
                sw.Start();
            }

            // Если передали конец
            if (data.Last().Contains("end"))
            {
                // Останавливаем счетчик
                sw.Stop();
                // Выводим результат
                Debug.WriteLine("end. " + sw.Elapsed);
            }

            // Ждем следующих данных
            ns.BeginRead(buff, 0, 0, read_buff_size, ns);

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Останавливаем сервер
            is_server_running = false;
            // Закрываем все подключения
            tcp_listener.Server.Close();
            // Останавливаем слушатель
            tcp_listener.Stop();            
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

А может лучше (на выбор):

1. Объявить функции из си++'ной библиотеки в шарпе и вызывать их напрямую.
2. Скомпилировать саму библиотеку на managed c++.
3. Сделать переходник к библиотеке на managed c++.
4. Вместо библиотеки сделать com-объект и использовать его си кода на C#.

Comment: 1. Дело в том, что c++ библиотеку вызывает третья программа. Она передает свои данные, а c++ уже пишет в память. Сразу скажу, что нельзя реализовать напрямую передачу из третьей программы в c#.

В принципе это ответ на все пункты. Событие происходит в C++. Там появляются данные, которые нужно передать в C#.

Answer (score 0):

А через сокет не проще данные передать?

Comment: А разве сокет быстрее работает чем именованная память?

Comment: @Dzam, в вашем случае - быстрее. Ведь вы пытаетесь передать поток байт, а общие отображаемые на память файлы нужны для разделения сложных структур данных между процессами.

Comment: Провел тестирование и обновил вопрос. Скорость не изменилась. Возможно я не так использую сокеты?

Comment: Вы зря крутите слушатель в активном ожидании. Читайте новое сообщение сразу же после предыдущего.

Comment: Не совсем понял фразу "крутите слушатель в активном ожидании".

Comment: @Dzam никогда не пишите алгоритмов, которым требуется `Thread.Sleep(1)`. Зачем вы пытаетесь дождаться прихода нового сообщения в холостом цикле - когда можно начать чтение и ОС подождет данные за вас?